# Problems piping sed output to grep through xargs

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, xargs

I am having problems piping `sed` output to be used with `grep` through `xargs`. I think it is a problem of variable expansion, but I am not sure.

The scenario is as follows. Current directory has these files:

```
file1.log
file1.log.67654
file2.log
file2.log.66876
file3.log
file3.log.56768
...
```

From these files, only some of the ones ending in `.log` contain a certain string so that:

```
$ grep -l "certainString"
file1.log
file3.log
```

What I want is to find how many of these files OR the ones that start like these but have additional `.numbers` as extension (files `file1.log`, `file1.log.67654`, `file3.log` and `file3.log.56768` in this example) contain another string.

I thought that this command would do it:

```
grep -l "certainString" | sed "s/log/log*/g" | xargs grep -l "anotherString"
```

But after I replace `log` with `log*` with `sed`, `xargs` does not expand the `*` but inteprets it literally, therefore:

```
$ grep -l "certainString" | sed "s/log/log*/g" | xargs grep -l "anotherString"
grep: ./file1.log*: No such file or directory
grep: ./file3.log*: No such file or directory
```

I have read about this and people suggest using something like:

```
grep -l "certainString" | sed "s/log/log*/g" | xargs -I@ sh -c 'grep -l "anotherString"'
```

But I can´t make it work (I do not fully understand it, to be honest). I feel I am just there but I am missing a detail. Any help?

Comment: because globbing (filename expansion) is done by the shell not by the process `grep`

Comment: Why would you *expect* `xargs` to do expansion?  That's a shell feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case file names doesn't contain spaces or globbing metacharater (`* [ ]`)

Just add `@`, because `-I@` means that `@` is a token to be replaced by argument

```
grep -l "certainString" | sed "s/log/log*/g" | xargs -I@ sh -c 'grep -l "anotherString" @'
```